# How to use SwapBuffers() outside class "wxGLCanvas"?

Tags: c++, opengl, wxwidgets

I'm using OpenGL to draw graphics in wxWidgets.

```
class BasicGLPane : public wxGLCanvas 
...
  void BasicGLPane::render( wxPaintEvent& evt ){
  glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glVertex3f(0,0,0);
  glVertex3f(getWidth(),0,0);
  glVertex3f(getWidth(),getHeight(),0);
  glVertex3f(0,getHeight(),0);
  glEnd();
  SwapBuffers();
}
```

In this render function, I can use SwapBuffers() to display my last OpenGL command. But if I call SwapBuffers() in that functions so the result can't be displayed.

How to use SwapBuffers() outside the class wxGLCanvas? Or is there any way to display the result of OpenGL commands without SwapBuffers()?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Did you try calling `wxGLCanvas::SwapBuffers()` from outside? Just remember to make the context current before calling the `gl*` commands.

Comment: *"But if I call SwapBuffers() in that functions so the result can't be displayed."*  Please explain this sentence.